# Mysql slow query log issue...?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-replication, database-administration, database-performance

Analyzing the slow query log of my mysql database server, i found an interesting query taking more time and making issues in performance of my application.Please help me to find out the issue ?

```
# Query_time: 481  Lock_time: 0  Rows_sent: 25571220  Rows_examined: 25571220

  SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `closing_stock`;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a dump of the table.  Are you running backups too often or something like that?

Comment: @Jayakrishnan, @JamesRyan is absolutely correct !!! +1 for Him. This is exactly what mysqldump does.

Comment: yes its correct.